# How should I step down from my position as acting supervisor?

Tags: management

I have been acting supervisor for a year now and I believe I have more then proven I am capable for the position. The issue is that there is no position available and my team headcount has been shrinking. It is now essential that I perform routine tasks while scheduling and coordinating tasks for the rest of my team, which has caused me increased stress. There is also no hope of the "acting" being removed anytime soon so I would like to step down. Can they force me to continue as acting supervisor?

Comment: Who becomes the supervisor if you step down?

Comment: Have you tried pretending to enjoy supervising so much that your co-workers become jealous and plot to steal your job?

Comment: My bosses would have to take over coordinating tasks which I'm sure they will not be happy about

Comment: Have you told them about these troubles you are having, and if so what did they say?

Comment: I don't understand how you can be "acting" supervisor but they don't have an open position available for full supervisor. That indicates to me that the company is very poorly run and you should consider looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

> Can they force me to continue as acting supervisor?

No. Slavery has been abolished. If your real question is "Is my employer required to find a different role for me if I no longer want to be acting supervisor but wish to continue being employed by my current employer?" then the answer is **no** (though they might consider it).

Comment: They also might consider your not a good fit for any job.  Saying you can't do something isn't a good statement to make.

Comment: @Ramhound Depends on the circumstances. It is actually quite common in software engineering that people want to return to being worker drones after trying management for a bit, and many companies are fine with allowing that.

Comment: I am well aware of that.  Important to point out the risks.  They can indeed force the author  to be a Supervisor considering they offer monetary compensation for it

Comment: There was no pay increase when I became acting supervisor, which is why the increase in responsibility is not worth it with no prospect of a real promotion soon.

Answer (score 4):

It's been done many times. The main problem is that it makes future prospects of advancement harder to achieve. You get labeled as not management material, or fails under pressure. Particularly if you remain with the company.

But short term your immediate risk is that they just demote you out the door.

Comment: Agree.  With a shrinking team, the supervisory responsibilities diminish.  If the prospects are good for future expansion, as is, OP can be seen as ripe for promotion.  If he follows through with his plan, he will likely be let go.  Now if there is no prospect of future expansion, it might be time to move on anyway.